# What is this gVim warning and how to eliminate it?

Tags: vim, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

In Ubuntu 10.04 (as a Virtual Machine), I open gVim from command line but every time I switch from terminal to vim and back I see the following warning:

`** (gvim:13790): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion 'height >= -1' failed`

Why do I get this warning and how do I get rid of it?

The installation (via software center) is pretty much unmodified, except the addition of ~/.vimrc:

```
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin
set hls
```

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/538499

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in the theme package(s). Resolution here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/538499/comments/24

Modify the entry in `/usr/share/themes/YOUR THEME IN USE/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` from `GtkRange::trough-under-steppers = 0` to `GtkRange::trough-under-steppers = 1`

HTH

Comment: Thanks. (annoying filler due to minimum comment length)